# Ajax post request from Backbone to Laravel

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, laravel

I'm trying to send a Backbone collection to Laravel with an Ajax Request.
I don't need to save it or update the database I just need to process the data with the Omnypay php Api. Unfortunately the Laravel Controller variable $input=Input::all() contain an empty string.

```
    var url = 'index.php/pay';
    var items = this.collection.toJSON;      

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: items,
        success:function (data) {             
        if(data.error) {  // If there is an error, show the error messages
                $('.alert-error').text(data.error.text).show();
            }            
        }
    });
```

This is the Laravel Route:

```
Route::post('pay','PaypalController@doPay');
```

And finally the Laravel Controller:

```
class PaypalController extends BaseController {

public function doPay() {

        $input=Input::all();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack solution I found to transfer a backbone collection to Laravel was to convert the collection to JSON and then wrapping it in a plain object, suitable for the jQuery Ajax POST. Here is the Code:

```
var url = 'index.php/pay';
var items = this.collection.toJSON();
var plainObject= {'obj': items}; 

$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:"json",
    data: plainObject,
    success:function (data) {             
    if(data.error) {  // If there is an error, show the error messages
            $('.alert-error').text(data.error.text).show();
        }            
    }
});
```

Now the $input variable of my "doPay" controller function contain an array of Backbone models.

Answer (score 0):

Your `route` doesn't match, it's

```
Route::post('pay','PaypalController@doPay');
```

So the url should be

```
var url = 'pay';
```

instead of

```
var url = 'index.php/pay';
```

BTW, not sure if anything else (backnone) is wrong.

**Update :** `toJSON` is a method, so it should be (you missed `()`)

```
var items = this.collection.toJSON();
```

Comment: Hi thx for the reply, if I change the url I get " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". I'm a bit confused: debugging the php I can see that Laravel route call the right controller, do you think this is still an URL issue?

Comment: Are you sure that url is available and works from address bar ?

Comment: from address bar I get this response "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

Comment: It's ok, should not work because it's a `post` route, try to use route::get, only for checking and undo it again but it's available i  think.

Comment: @Cris69, Does that work when you use it with `index.php/pay` ?

Comment: from the browser address bar using the `Route::get` it works, from the debugger I get: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: This `500` error is being occurred because most probably you have errors in your code.